# Scraping Wikipedia information (table)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would need to scrape information regarding Elenco dei comuni per regione on Wikipedia. I would like to create an array that can allow me to associate each comune to the corresponding region, i.e. something like this:

```
'Abbateggio': 'Pescara' -> Abruzzo
```

I tried to get information using `BeautifulSoup` and `requests` as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

     with requests.Session() as s: # use session object for efficiency of tcp re-use
        s.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
        r = s.get('https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comuni_d%27Italia')
        soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
        for ele in soup.find_all('h3')[:6]:
            tx = bs(str(ele),'html.parser').find('span', attrs={'class': "mw-headline"})
            if tx is not None:
                print(tx['id'])
```

however it does not work (it returns me an empty list). 
The information that I have looked at using Inspect of Google Chrome are the following:

```
<span class="mw-headline" id="Elenco_dei_comuni_per_regione">Elenco dei comuni per regione</span> (table)

<a href="/wiki/Comuni_dell%27Abruzzo" title="Comuni dell'Abruzzo">Comuni dell'Abruzzo</a>
```

(this field should change for each region)

then `<table class="wikitable sortable query-tablesortes">`

Could you please give me advice on how to get such results?
Any help and suggestion will be appreciated.

EDIT:

Example:

I have a word: `comunediabbateggio`. This word includes `Abbateggio`. I would like to know which region can be associated with that city, if it exists. 
Information from Wikipedia needs to create a dataset that can allow me to check the field and associate to comuni/cities a region. 
What I should expect is:

```
WORD                         REGION/STATE
comunediabbateggio           Pescara
```

I hope this can help you. Sorry if it was not clear. 
Another example for English speaker that might be slightly better for understanding is the following:

Instead of the Italian link above, you can also consider the following: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_comuni_of_Italy . For each region (Lombardia, Veneto, Sicily, ... ) I would need to collect information about the `list of communes of the Provinces`. 
if you click in a link of `List of Communes of ...` , there is a table that list the comune, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_communes_of_the_Province_of_Agrigento.

Comment: What were the results of your debugging attempts?

Comment: I suggest you break the code up into functions and test each function. That way you can have an easier time debugging and you get good programming habits for free!

Comment: i can,t see any variable that u used to define as variable for "com.append(results[x])"

Comment: I updated the code after comment from Shane. But I am still far away from the solution (unfortunately)

Comment: Please define the result variable first.

Comment: please paste ur full code not half

Comment: This is what I have done until now, but it is not working (this is the part that should allow me to get first information before scraping the other information)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm



target = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_comuni_of_Italy"


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        r = req.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

        provinces = [item.find_next("span").text for item in soup.findAll(
            "span", class_="tocnumber", text=re.compile(r"\d[.]\d"))]

        search = [item.replace(
            " ", "_") if " " in item else item for item in provinces]

        nested = []
        for item in search:
            for a in soup.findAll("span", id=item):
                goes = [b.text.split("of ")[-1]
                        for b in a.find_next("ul").findAll("a")]
                nested.append(goes)

        dictionary = dict(zip(provinces, nested))

        urls = [f'{url[:24]}{b.get("href")}' for item in search for a in soup.findAll(
            "span", id=item) for b in a.find_next("ul").findAll("a")]
    return urls, dictionary


def parser():
    links, dics = main(target)
    com = []
    for link in tqdm(links):
        try:
            df = pd.read_html(link)[0]
            com.append(df[df.columns[1]].to_list()[:-1])
        except ValueError:
            com.append(["N/A"])
    com = iter(com)
    for x in dics:
        b = dics[x]
        dics[x] = dict(zip(b, com))
    print(dics)


parser()
```

Comment: Thank you Ahmed, but unfortunately your code does not answer my question. I would need to get information that can allow me to have association `Abbateggio': 'Pescara' -> Abruzzo` (list + zip). For each `comune` (e.g. `Pescara`), I would need the `city` (e.g. `Abbateggio`) and the `region` (e.g. `Abruzzo`).

Comment: @Val your question is not clear. from where those is obtained ? are it's within the `HTML` source and you want to convert it to `array` ?

Comment: I would like to create an array/list that stores all the information regarding comune, city, and region in order to check later if a string contains an element (e.g. comune or city or region), then associating the corresponding region. For example: I have a word like `comunediabbateggio`: this word includes `abbateggio`. I would need to create a new column that can store information about the region (`Abruzzo`) for that element/word (`comunediabbateggio`). The information collected from Wikipedia page needs t create a dataset with all the possible comuni, cities and regions.

Comment: I included an example. My apologies if it was not clear. I was focusing in exampling what I was trying to do and I did not give you an example of output. @αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη

Comment: if you click in a link of List of Communes of ... , there is a table that list the comune, e.g. `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_communes_of_the_Province_of_Agrigento`. The words that I mentioned (Abbateggio, Pescara) were taken as reference to let people easier spot the field in the link. I do not know them neiither

Comment: @Val well ! here is the big  **POINT** ever, you haven't included such information for your question and even didn't described that you want to get the `state` and the corresponding `city` for it into array after parse the `linker` url for it! if that's the case, let me know so i can start work on it. i really have been taken time to search within the original page to understand your concern.

Comment: State for me means country. But with region probably I mean what you call state. Apologies for the confusion

Comment: @Val Just to confirm. your end target is like **"Chieti": {"Altino", "Archi", ...}** and so on?