# Need to Extract html link in Jupyter

Tags: dataframe, jupyter-notebook, wikipedia

I looked through as many repositories as I could possible find and there is a missing piece to writing code that extracts elements from a Wikipedia page in addition the  for each city.

```
    import pandas as pd
    url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_in_New_York'

    df=pd.read_html(url, header=0)[0]

    df.head()


    import pandas
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    website_text = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_in_New_York').text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(website_text,'xml')

    table = soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable'})

    table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

    data = []
         for row in table_rows:
              data.append([t.text.strip() for t in row.find_all('td')])
              df = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=['City', 'PostalCode', 
                  'Population','IncorpDate','FIPS_Sub','FIPS_Place'])
              df = df[~df['PostalCode'].isnull()]  # to filter out bad rows
    df.head()

    df.to_csv('ny_cities22.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

I know it's probably something I am missing but I cannot figure out the code.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scraping Wikipedia information (table)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61021901/scraping-wikipedia-information-table)

Comment: What, exactly, is the result of this code? Is there an error, is nothing written to the CSV file, only the headers, only the first city, only the last city? Also, since indentation matters in Python, can you double-check the formatting? I think the for loop should only contain the `data.append()` call, but its hard to tell if that is what the actual code looks like.

Comment: It worked on my PC but what it does not gather is the link in the a href.  Here is a sample layout.  

,City,PostalCode,Population,IncorpDate,FIPS_Sub,FIPS_Place
1,Albany,Albany,"97,856",1686,3600101000,3601000